# How use File("/sdcard/myfile") without READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE on android 11?

Tags: java, android, android-manifest, mediastore

After my Application have been refused by the play Store I have to remove MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE to the manifest. This authorisation is only for app like antivirus or file manager.

I need to get a file like this :

`File file = new File("/sdcard/Download/Myfile.pdf");`

This actually produce the following error on android 11 :

`FILE NOT FOUND/sdcard/Download/GE-ACTIONS-03.pdf: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)`

Are there a possibility to get The `File` in this way ?

I need this file to create a `fileInputStream` like this :

`fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);`

(I already read other answer on stack overflow but they all use MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE.)

Answer (score 0):

well, question in title is pretty clear, same as answer: you can't. these all permissions and restrictions are created for purpose (securing user), not for breaking/ommiting them

currently on newest system versions you have to use [Scoped Storage](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/storage#app-specific-external) and you can freely store files onle there. afaik you can get access to Download folder (and other media ones) using [Media Store API](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/storage#media-file-access), but on devices with Scoped Storage your app will see only own files stored in this folder (downloaded by itself, not by another apps)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, there are things that I not get it : In this link they say that we can use File API https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/storage#media-direct-file-native

Answer (score 0):

The issue is faced by me too. When you try saving a file to the `sdcard`, please make sure that **not all the devices have `sdcard`**. So, it will throw `FileNotFoundException`. So, you might try using a different storage directory.This way you do not need any permission!

Answer (score -1):

You should first use `File.exists()` and then `File.canRead()`.

The latter will return false if your app did not create the file.

If your app did not create the file let the user pick the file with `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Has said in this part we cannot access to download directory with ```ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT``` or ```ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE```. https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/documents-files#document-tree-access-restrictions

Comment: Please read better. The user cannot choose the`Download` directory with `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE` indeed. But the user can pick any file from `Download` directory using `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT`. And of course you can use all File api's. Only check before if a file exists and you have read and or write access. Whatever you need.

Comment: You need to start using the Storage Access Framework and call the FilePicker to let the user grant access to certain folders.